# Unable to import matplotlib in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

The following code results in an error.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.stats import skew
```

The error is

```
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.scale' has no attribute 'AsinhScale'
```

I've tried a bunch of different ways to fix this including uninstalling and reinstalling matplotlib, updating to the latest version but that hasn't worked

Comment: Could you share your entire program - not just the import statements?

Comment: Try `!pip install matplotlib --upgrade`

Comment: Ideally, the magic `%pip` should be used @Keworker. It was added in 2019 to insure actions occur in the environment where the kernel is running. The exclamation point alone doesn't do that and can thus lead to problems and confusion. Please suggest current best practices and not outdated advice that may lead to problems. See more about the modern `%pip install` command [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez).

Comment: <continued> [The second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues.

Comment: And if you are trying to narrow down what causes the issue, it should be one line in one cell and not three. You can say that you have to run the other two first, or something along that line but you should specify what specific line causes the issue. Usually the traceback provides all this and should be provided. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow it as a guide to making a post. Include the error message as described there. Not a single line of it.

Comment: Thanks all for your responses. I just restarted the kernel and everything seems to work just fine now. The import was successful. I'm not sure why this worked today as I tried restarting the kernel yesterday as well but that didn't do the trick.